# Killed: 9 to process with no explanation

Tags: macos, cordova, ionic-framework, npm, sigint

Running `ionic lab` or `ionic serve` terminates without any explanation with `Killed: 9`. Activity monitor shows that an ionic thread does not already exist and that when it is started it only uses .3% CPU and 25.3 MB of memory. This same behavior happens when I try to run on the ios emulator.It seemed to be breaking before the "deeplinks", so my guess is something like that is broken.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling node, npm, ionic and cordova.

I'm happy to post any other commands that would help troubleshooting.

Answer (score 3):

This also happens if bash is updated while it is running.

For example, you run `brew upgrade bash` or something like that. Bash is being updated and thus is killed first. No matter what command you try you get `Killed: 9`.

Answer (score 0):

So didn't really figure out the problem.. but solved this by following this article:
http://stackabuse.com/how-to-uninstall-node-js-from-mac-osx/
and then running `find / '*node*'` and deleting all related node files. 
I did the same with rm -rf all `find / '*npm*' and`find / *ionic*`and`find / *cordova*`. After that I ran`brew doctor`and then`brew prune`. I was not allowed to delete a broken link, so ultimately uninstalled homebrew and restarted my machine.

After that I tried to cleanly install brew, node, npm, ionic and cordova and chose to remake my ionic project and port over changes from the old one rather than fighting with `npm install` over the `package.json` dependencies that were outdated in the old ionic project according to `npm audit`.

I don't know if any of this can help anyone else, other than a story in being careful with installs and the glory (and confusion) of package managers. It is always possible to get a clean state again and sometimes it might be the easiest way forward.

Maybe someone else sees some hints that could clarify what exactly might have gone wrong.